# How can I make Mouse/Keyboard drivers to work?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, downloads, dpi

What can I do if I want to download a mouse/keyboard driver but it's not native with Linux, how can I adjust DPI, and the RGB lighting?

Comment: I have a Trust GXT 166, and I want to change for a SteelSeries Rival 100, I can't use both of the advantages what they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use a [virtual machine](http://www.howtogeek.com/196060/beginner-geek-how-to-create-and-use-virtual-machines/) running windows & Trust drivers to configure it
2. Dual boot with windows. 
   Sorry linux can't adjust DPI or the RGB lighting of your mouse :(

Comment: Trust GXT 166, but I want to change for a SteelSeries Rival 100, or Razer Naga Epic Chroma.

Comment: Your where right that the Trust GTX 166 mouse does not have native linux drivers.  linux suport for the  SteelSeries Rival 100  is a about the same. but you can configure it on windows. maybe try a Virtual machine with windows to configure it. or [link] WINE (https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/what-is-wine) _italic_ **bold** `code`